# Python regex for detecting additions

Tags: python, regex

I've a string that could be like this:

```
50W
800W+25W
30W+50W+2W
```

I would like to check if the current string matches and extract those numerical values.

Actually, I've done this:

```
re.compile("^(\d+W\+)*(\d+W)$")
```

The problem is that if I use the star *, it always get the first element of the first group (for example, for `50W+20W+30W` I get `["50W+", "30W"]` (I'm using `re.findall`)

I don't know how to get the all the groups and how can I strip directly from the regex the "W" and the "+" characters (maybe I should use `re.split`?).

**Edit 1** - I don't know if the string is like this: I've to check first, then I can extract the numbers

Comment: Have you tried using the non-greedy form of star?  i.e.  `*?`

Comment: @KennethK.: it doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split()` is a better approach here, in my opinion.

```
In [1]: '50W'.split('+')
Out[1]: ['50W']

In [2]: '800W+25W'.split('+')
Out[2]: ['800W', '25W']

In [3]: '30W+50W+2W'.split('+')
Out[3]: ['30W', '50W', '2W']
```

If you want to strip off the character `W` from each list entry, just use slicing and convert the resulting string to an integer:

```
In [4]: int('30W'[:-1])
Out[4]: 30
```

In order to check whether a string is of this format, you can use this simple regex:

```
In [5]: pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+W(?:\+\d+W)*$')
```

To summarize, I would do it like this:

```
In [6]: vals = ['50W', '800W+25W', '30W+50W+2W', '80W3000W2675W']

In [7]: for val in vals:
  ....:     if pattern.match(val):
  ....:         numbers = val.split('+')
  ....:         print [int(num[:-1]) for num in numbers]
[50]
[800, 25]
[30, 50, 2]
```

Comment: I don't know if the string is like this, I have to check first.

Comment: Note that the pattern at the end rejects `40W` (no addition) as input.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, I just noticed that myself. Fixed it. Now it works as shown in my example code.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regexes for extracting these values.

```
In [1]: [int(e[:-1]) for e in "30W+50W+2W".split('+')]
Out[1]: [30, 50, 2]

In [2]: [int(e[:-1]) for e in "800W+25W".split('+')]
Out[2]: [800, 25]

In [3]: [int(e[:-1]) for e in "50W".split('+')]
Out[3]: [50]
```

You might want to use a regex to check if the string matches this pattern, but we don't know enough of your situation.

You can use positive lookaheads to search for digits followed by `W`:

```
In [16]: re.findall('\d+(?=W)', '30W+50W+2W')
Out[16]: ['30', '50', '2']

In [17]: re.findall('\d+(?=W)', '30W+50W')
Out[17]: ['30', '50']

In [18]: re.findall('\d+(?=W)', '30W')
Out[18]: ['30']
```

You can't check if a string is strictly `^(\d+W\+)*(\d+W)$` *and* extract these numbers.

Comment: First I've to check if the string is like this, then I could extract the informations. I thought to use regex to get them because I need to use to understand if the string is in this format.

Comment: I'd still first validate with a regexp, then extract separately.

Comment: Thanks, but it shouldn't match strings like "30W50W". Should I use another regex for matching and your regex for extracting the informations, or can I use only one regex?

Comment: For the second solution: Note that `(?=\+)?` doesn't do anything, since it can be skipped, due to `?`. So `30W50W60W`, which is likely invalid, will constitute a pass. Another thing is that there is no guarantee the next match starts from where the last match left off, so `30W+garbage+40W` will also constitute a pass, and the garbage is ignored.

Comment: Thanks, so I need first to check it, then to get the values.

Comment: @nhahtdh. Yes, sorry about that, this is several kinds of wrong. `\d+(?=W)(?=\+)` doesn't even match `30W+`. You can't chain lookaheads like this. But garbage I did consider, this was meant for extracting numbers, not validating the string.

Comment: @PavelAnossov: If the string has been validated, I'd go for simple `\d+` for extraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you like functional programming in python, you may use

```
>>> newlist = ['50W', '800W+25W', '30W+50W+2W', '80W3000W2675W']
>>> map(lambda x: re.findall(r"(\d+)W", x), 
        filter(lambda x: re.match('^\d+W(\+\d+W)*$',x), newlist))
[['50'], ['800', '25'], ['30', '50', '2']]
```